# Perl String parsing multiple patterns

Tags: string, perl, parsing, split

I'm trying to parse text file which has multiple patters.
Goal is to have everything in between * * and only integer in between ^ ^ it should remove all special character or string if found.

data.txt

```
*ABC-13077* ^817266, 55555^
*BCD-13092* ^CL: 816933^
*CDE-13127* ^  ===>   Change 767666 submitted^
```

output.txt

```
ABC-13077 817266 55555
BCD-13092 816933
CDE-13127 767666
```

my script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Cwd;
my $var;

open(FH,"changelists.txt")or die("can't open file:$!");
while($var=<FH>)
{
    my @vareach=split(/[* \s\^]+/,$var);
    for my $each(@vareach)
    {
        print "$each\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the * and ^ just markers, or do they really exist in the input?

Comment: they do exist in the input.

Comment: but you do want to have multiple numbers in a line seperated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the while loop with the following:

```
while (<FH>) {
    s/\*(.*)\*/$1/;
    s/\^(.*)\^/ join ' ', $1 =~ m([0-9]+)g /e;
    print;
}
```

The first substitution removes the asterisks.

The second substitution takes the `^...^` part, and replaces it with the result of the code in the replacement part because of the `/e` modifier. The code matches all the integers, and as `join` forces list context on the match, it returns all the matches.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help Choroba.. but i'm getting error "Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line1." can i run as "perl -pe 's/\*(.*)\*/$1/;s/\^(.*)\^/ join " ", $1 =~ m([0-9]+)g /e' data.txt"

Comment: windows.. perl v5.8.3

Comment: @Mihir: Oh, I see. Try switching the quotes.

Comment: I did try, now i'm getting "Substitution replacement not terminated at -e line 1."